# I am trying to create a user registration with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

this is my model:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ingredients = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    process = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    poster_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

class Users(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    birthday = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

this is my serialiser:

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Recipe
            fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'ingredients', 'process',             'post_date', 'poster_id' ]
    
    
    
    
    class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password2'},    write_only=True) 
        
        class Meta:
            model = Users
            fields = ['id', 'full_name', 'username', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday',    'password', 'password2']
            extra_kwargs = {
                'password': {'write_only': True}
            }
    
        def save(self):
            user =    Users(full_name=self.validated_data['full_name'],username=self.validated_data['username'],
                email=self.validated_data['email'],
                gender=self.validated_data['gender'],
                birthday=self.validated_data['birthday'],
                )
    
            password=self.validated_data['password']
            password2=self.validated_data['password2']
    
            if password != password2:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'password must mactch'})
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return user


This is my view code:

    @api_view(['POST'])
    def registration_view(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
            data = {}
            if serializer.is_valid():
                user = serializer.save()
                data['response'] = "successfully registerd a new user"
                data['username'] = user.username
                data['email'] = user.email
    
            else:
                data = serializer.errors
            return Response(data)
```

This is the error I encountered:

```
Internal Server Error: /register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/DjangoProjects/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/user/DjangoProjects/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/DjangoProjects/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/DjangoProjects/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/DjangoProjects/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/user/DjangoProjects/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/user/DjangoProjects/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/user/DjangoProjects/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/DjangoProjects/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/DjangoProjects/recipe/views.py", line 56, in registration_view
    user = serializer.save()
  File "/Users/user/DjangoProjects/recipe/serializers.py", line 37, in save
    user.set_password(password)
AttributeError: 'Users' object has no attribute 'set_password'
[25/May/2022 23:18:07] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 92797
```

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. I even copied word for word from the tutorial but I am getting a very different result. Initially I thought its because I didn't enter the password2 into the model. I decided to change it and did some migrations but nothing changed. I still the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your ```User``` model doesn't have a ```set_password``` method.  I believe you just need to ```user.password = password```.

Comment: Or, much more probably, you need [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). You're missing the fact that it has to subclass `AbstractUser`.

Answer (score 0):

The `set_password` function is the member function of the `AbstractUser` class.
So the `User` model should be inherited from the `AbstarctUser`.
And the `AbstractUser` model has already some fields, so you don't have to define all the fields.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Users(AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    birthday = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

And in settings.py file, you need to set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` value.
For example, if the current app name is `accounts`, you can set the auth user model like the following.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Users'
```